# Hibernate relationship one to one

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, one-to-one

I use hibernate + spring. I have 2 table:

```
teacher      class
-------      ----
id           id
name         name
class_id     teacher_id
```

teacher may have only 1 class or null.
class may have only 1 teacher or null.

I think that i must use one-to-one relationship but i don't know how.
I use annotations.

Comment: Sounds like a many-to-many relationship. Why don't you use a join table?

Answer (score 0):

You use the OneToOne annotation.

From the reference guide, an example with FK references:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="passport_fk")
    public Passport getPassport() {
        ...
    }

@Entity
public class Passport implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "passport")
    public Customer getOwner() {
    ...
}
```

More examples: [Hibernate 3.5 reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association)